# MIDI interface which is compatible with 2010 macbook pro

Tags: midi

I am looking for a MIDI interface for my 2010 macbook pro.  I currently have a MAudio midisport 4x4 which has always served me well but it is USB powered and it seems that the macbook pro does not put out enough electricity over USB to power it.  The USB light does not even turn on.  I also only really need 1 in and 1 out so it is a little over kill.  Almost all of the other MIDI interfaces I have seen are also USB powered so I am worried I will run into the same problem.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: In addition to the suggestions below, you might also consider a self-powered hub.  There are many to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I ended up with a motu fastlane: http://www.motu.com/products/midi/fastlane_usb/.  No power problems but it does not work well with a hub.  I have it plugged directly into the mac.  It also required a driver update to work with intel macs.

Comment: I've got an M-Audio Uno and I'm having some problems with it. Not yet totally sure the blame lies with the Uno but it's looking probable, and there are quite a few negative reviews and reports of issues with this device -- makes me wish I'd done some research first. I'd say definitely follow up any suggestions you get here with a bit of Googling for reviews both positive and negative to get the complete picture.

Answer (score 3):

I use a [Roland/CalkWalk UM-1G](http://www.rolandus.com/products/productdetails.php?ProductId=1091&ParentId=436) USB MIDI interface with my 2010 MacBook Pro and it works without any issues at all.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a MIDI interface that has it's own power adapter, you may need to check out an audio interface with MIDI also.

The [M-Audio Fast Track Pro](http://www.guitarcenter.com/M-Audio-Fast-Track-Pro-Mobile-USB-Audio-MIDI-Interface-103520185-i1126084.gc) is a USB interface that has both audio and MIDI Inputs/Outputs and is compatible with both Mac and PC.  According to the specs, it can be powered by USB or by an *"optional"* AC power adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a MIDIsport UNO, but buy it from somewhere that has an exhange policy. It has worked fine on my Powerbook. Have you considered that it may be an issue

Comment: The 4x4 works fine with my tower.  I also read that the macbook USBs are low power.  It does seems a little strange though.  I cant imagine a MIDI interface would need that much juice.  Maybe its all the lights.

Answer (score 1):

I picked up an EMagic AMT8 from EBay for cheap, and it works perfectly with Snow Leopard on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with a Roland Edirol UM-2ex which is cheap and works well. However, you might want to consider the $150+ iConnect if you  have any use for that kind of connectivity.

On Macbook Pro 2011 with SL and now Lion.